# Recursively deleting a folder in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have the following code that *should* delete the directory and everything inside it.

It seems to work fine but for some reason I get the following **warnings** in my app engine logs when the code runs.

Does anyone know why this would happen or if there is a better way to avoid these errors?

> PHP Warning:  Cloud Storage Error: NOT FOUND in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams/CloudStorageDirectoryClient.php on line 223

```
function deleteDir($dirPath) 
{
    if (! is_dir($dirPath)) {
        die("not a directory");
    }
    if (substr($dirPath, strlen($dirPath) - 1, 1) != '/') {
        $dirPath .= '/';
    }
    $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            deleteDir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dirPath);
}

deleteDir("gs://folder/folder");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GCS doesn't actually have (sub)directories](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork#potential-for-surprising-destination-subdirectory-naming), they're "faked" by extracting them from the path-like segments of filenames:

> gsutil provides the illusion of a hierarchical file tree atop the
>   “flat” name space supported by the Google Cloud Storage service. To
>   the service, the object gs://your-bucket/abc/def/ghi.txt is just an
>   object that happens to have “/” characters in its name. There are no
>   “abc” or “abc/def” directories; just a single object with the given
>   name.

[image]

So you don't actually need the `rmdir($dirPath);` statement (I suspect that's the one causing the warning).

Comment: Thanks for the information! That worked perfectly. Very weird that it lets me create a fake folder in the console with nothing inside it - yet, when I remove this statement, it ends up removing the folder entirely.

Comment: That's just how the hierarchical structure emulation works. The "directory creation" is just a no-op (you won't actually find it after "creation" unless you also create a file in it). You should be able to create the file even _without_ creating its parent directory. The "directory removal" happens because of the `unlink($file);` or `deleteDir($file);` statements invoked for each `$file` in the directory - once all content is removed the directory itself dissapears automatically (no remaining file with the directory name at the beginning of its filename, no way to "fake" the dir's existance)

Comment: When you create a folder in the console, a zero-byte object is created with the folder name. So, for example, if you create a folder called `blah` in a folder called `test`, then the zero-byte object will be named `gs://bucket/test/blah/` (trailing slash included). Note: this object will only be created when creating a folder through the console. It's needed to show the folder so users can navigate into the folder.