# Google cloudstorage returns 404 Not Found when trying to delete from bucket

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to delete a file (video) from Google Cloud Storage via the cloudstorage api but although the file exists I'm getting the following error:

```
cloudstorage.delete('/catchamove-video/products/6411421952770048.mp4')

*** NotFoundError: Expect status [204] from Google Storage. But got status 404.
Path: '/catchamove-video/products/6411421952770048.mp4'.
Request headers: None.
Response headers: {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'date': 'Sun, 07 May 2017 12:31:47 GMT', 'server': 'Development/2.0'}.
Body: ''.
Extra info: None.
```

Both the bucket and file are present on the console.

Comment: We are having same problems.

We use laravel and https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage package, and with the help of service account key json file, we are able to create files, but when we want to delete a folder, we get 404 error...

We tried to add the all storage permissions to client email which is used in the key, tried also to add allUsers permissions to service account, no luck

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem: getting 404 when delete a folder via REST API.

After some tests, I figured out how delete folder of GCP storage -

Have to delete all files (objects) in the folder, files in sub-folders and sub-folders and folder. Be noticed that when deleting empty folder, you may still get "404 Not Found"(normally gets 204), just ignore it and the empty folder will be actually deleted.

Examples:

```
curl -I -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Bearer <author_code>" https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<bucket_name>/o/folder%2Fsub-folder%2Ffile1

curl -I -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Bearer <author_code>" https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<bucket_name>/o/folder%2Fsub-folder%2Ffile2

curl -I -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Bearer <author_code>" https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<bucket_name>/o/folder%2Fsub-folder%2F  #May get 204 or 404 response code

curl -I -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Bearer <author_code>" https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<bucket_name>/o/folder%2F #May get 204 or 404 response code
```

NOTE: "%2F" in the URL is actually "/" character

Comment: Your case is different - attempting to delete a folder, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655774/recursively-deleting-a-folder-in-google-cloud-storage/35656483#35656483

Comment: I know GCP storage does not actually have folder thing, but in GCP console, it does allow to create an empty 'folder'. In some case, you just wanna delete this empty folder which GCP think it's not an object so return 404.